# GridView Binding Error There is no row at position 11

Tags: c#, gridview

I've been trying to bind grid view to a datatable using DataSource but I am getting this error on .DataBind() method. I don't understand why I am getting this error because when I debug and look at my dt it contains 11 rows.
*

```
                        dt = itemCollection.GetDataTable();
                        dt = CreateDT(dt);
                        ViewState["dt"] = null;
                        ViewState["dt"] = dt;
                        GV.DataSource = dt;
                        GV.DataBind();//Error occurs here
```

- 

CreateDT method

```
protected DataTable CreateDT(DataTable dt2)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt.Columns.Add("Activity", typeof(string));

                dt.Columns.Add("OffsiteOnsite", typeof(DropDownList));
                dt.Columns.Add("Tobefilledby", typeof(DropDownList));
                dt.Columns.Add("Level1", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Level2", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Level3", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Level4", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Level5", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Level6", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Level7", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Level8", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("LastUpdatedBy", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Comments", typeof(string));

             

                for (int i = 0; i < dt2.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                    dr["Activity"] = dt2.Rows[i]["Activities"].ToString();
                  // dr["Tobefilledby"] = dt2.Rows[i]["To_x0020_be_x0020_filled_x0020_b"].ToString(); 
                   // dr["OffsiteOnsite"] = dt2.Rows[i]["Location_x0020_Type"].ToString();
                    dr["Level1"] = dt2.Rows[i]["Level1ManDays"].ToString(); 
                    dr["Level2"] = dt2.Rows[i]["Level2ManDays"].ToString(); 
                    dr["Level3"] = dt2.Rows[i]["Level3ManDays"].ToString(); 
                    dr["Level4"] = dt2.Rows[i]["Level4ManDays"].ToString(); 
                    dr["Level5"] = dt2.Rows[i]["Level5ManDays"].ToString(); 
                    dr["Level6"] = dt2.Rows[i]["Level6ManDays"].ToString(); 
                    dr["Level7"] = dt2.Rows[i]["Leve7lManDays"].ToString(); 
                    dr["Level8"] = dt2.Rows[i]["Level8ManDays"].ToString(); 
                    dr["Total"] = dt2.Rows[i]["Total"].ToString(); 
                    dr["LastUpdatedBy"] = dt2.Rows[i]["Last_x0020_updated_x0020_by"].ToString(); 
                    dr["Comments"] = dt2.Rows[i]["Comments"].ToString(); 

                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                return dt;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Do ask me if you think I haven't described it enough.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what I was doing was getting a new datatable and adding it to source of grid view that i was already using which caused this issue